# Matplotlib animation not displaying correctly in Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, matplotlib-animation

I know there are previous answers  to this question but for some reason I cannot seem to get the animation to show. Instead all the frames of the animation are overlayed in a figure that appears below the blank animation

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

# This is setup code
class_capacity = [100, 100, 100]
classes = ["CS1301", "CS1331", "CS1332"]
current_enrolled_students = [10, 0, 0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
#axes =fig.add_subplot()
axes.set_ylim(0, 100)

cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet")
```

```
def animate(i):
    axes.clear()
    axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
    for i in range(len(current_enrolled_students)):
        current_enrolled_students[i] = random.randint(0, class_capacity[i])
    barlist = plt.bar(classes, current_enrolled_students)
    for i in range(len(barlist)):
        barlist[i].set_color(cmap(current_enrolled_students[i] / class_capacity[i]))
```

```
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=400, blit=False, frames=9, repeat=False)
#plt.close()
#plt.show()
ani
```

I was trying to replicate a somewhat similar project found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ofuol9wHBJKxZlDS4foZ3cm9G8fArOow?usp=sharing)

I'm fairly certain the mistake is minor but I cannot figure out where exactly the problem is.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause is the use of plt.bar in the animation function. I think changing this to axes.bar() and closing the initial graph will complete the animation.

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

# This is setup code
class_capacity = [100, 100, 100]
classes = ["CS1301", "CS1331", "CS1332"]
current_enrolled_students = [10, 0, 0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
#axes =fig.add_subplot()
axes.set_ylim(0, 100)

cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet")

def animate(i):
    axes.clear()
    #axes.set_ylim(0, 100)
    for i in range(len(current_enrolled_students)):
        current_enrolled_students[i] = random.randint(0, class_capacity[i])
    barlist = axes.bar(classes, current_enrolled_students)
    for i in range(len(barlist)):
        barlist[i].set_color(cmap(current_enrolled_students[i] / class_capacity[i]))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=400, blit=False, frames=9, repeat=False)
plt.close()
#plt.show()
ani
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Thank to Kalibril, I can run animation on colab.

```
import matplotlib.animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
import random

plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = "jshtml"
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150  

plt.ioff()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_value = []
y_value = []
index = count();
def animate(t):
    x_value.append(next(index))
    y_value.append(random.randint(0,10))
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x_value,y_value)
    ax.set_xlim(0,10)

matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval = 500)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32799765)